# Realmのインデックスを使って、高速化

Tags: realm

50万件近くのデータをフェッチしたいのですが、検索キーにインデックスをはりたいと思います。
ただ一般的なDBの場合
部分一致検索で検索するとインデックスが効かず、遅くなると思います。それを避けるために
MySQLにはFULLTEXTインデック Oracle text等あるわけですが。realmではそういった昨日はあるでしょうか。また部分一致でもインデックスが効く方法が他にありましたらお教えください。

Comment: Realmに全文検索インデックスは作業中ですがまだリリースされていません。  Realmは部分一致でも相当速く検索できます。それとも何か具体的パフォーマンスの問題がありましたでしょうか？

Comment: なるほどありがとうございます。数十万件程度では問題ないということなのでしょうか。実際のデータが他のサイトでindexきいてる時のベンチマークはあったのですが、部分一致の場合はなかったのです。もしそういった検証サイトあればお教えください。

Comment: 一般的な話でたいていのケースでは問題ありません。検証といっても速い遅いというのは主観的なものなので、具体的にどんなケースでどれくらいの時間で検索できることを求めてますか？アプリケーションの要件やデータの内容にもよるのでそのへんをもう少し詳しく説明してください。とりあえずまだ何も試してないのでしたら問題があるのかどうか実際にやってみることをおすすめします。